# TypeScript: Type for any interface containing field and returning a transformed object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have 2 interfaces of which I know both have a field that is:

```
{
  [uuid: string]: string
}
```

Now I have a function that I want to be able to pass any interface that has that field and transform it:

```
private uuidMap<ElementTypes>(arr: ElementTypes[]): Record<string, ElementTypes> {
  return arr.reduce((obj, item) => ({ ...obj, [item.uuid]: item }), {});
}
```

this will transform

```
[
  { uuid: "a", value: "A" },
  { uuid: "b", value: "B" },
  { uuid: "c", value: "C" }
]
```

to this

```
{
  a: { uuid: "a", value: "A" },
  b: { uuid: "b", value: "B" },
  c: { uuid: "c", value: "C" }
}
```

Now I wonder how to properly write types for this;

How can I accept any array of objects having the field `[uuid: string]: string` and how do I return that object of  that type?

Comment: I think yo mean they have `{ uuid: string}`. `{ [uuid: string]: string }`  is an index signature, so they could have any field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a constraint on your generic type to let the compiler know that the type must contain an `uuid` property:

```
class Mapper {
    private uuidMap<ElementTypes extends { uuid: string }>(arr: ElementTypes[]): Record<string, ElementTypes> {
        return arr.reduce((obj, item) => ({ ...obj, [item.uuid]: item }), {});
    }
    test() {
        this.uuidMap([
            { uuid: "a", value: "A" },
            { uuid: "b", value: "B" },
            { uuid: "c", value: "C" }
        ]) 
        // Record<string, {
        //     uuid: string;
        //     value: string;
        // }>
    }
}
```

If you want to preserve property names contained in `uuid`, you can do this, using string literal types. This will only work if you invoke with object literals, but I include for completeness:

```
class Mapper {
    private uuidMap<ElementTypes extends { uuid: V }, V extends string>(arr: ElementTypes[]): { [P in ElementTypes['uuid']]: Extract<ElementTypes, { uuid: P }> } {
        return arr.reduce((obj, item) => ({ ...obj, [item.uuid]: item }), {}) as any;
    }
    test() {
        let d = this.uuidMap([
            { uuid: "a", value: "A" },
            { uuid: "b", value: "B" },
            { uuid: "c", value: "C" }
        ]) 
        // {
        //     a: {
        //         uuid: "a";
        //         value: string;
        //     };
        //     b: {
        //         uuid: "b";
        //         value: string;
        //     };
        //     c: {
        //         uuid: "c";
        //         value: string;
        //     };
        // }
    }
}
```